# Count frequency of occurrence in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to count value occurrences in a data frame which contains datetime column `('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`.

Data:

```
Date                        Employee        Operation        Order

2001-01-01 08:32:17         User1           Approved         #00045
2001-01-01 08:36:23         User1           Edited           #00045
2001-01-01 08:41:04         User1           Rejected         #00046
2001-01-01 08:42:56         User1           Deleted          #00046
2001-01-02 09:01:11         User1           Created          #00047
...
2019-10-03 17:23:45         User1           Approved         #72681
```

The issue I have is related to counting occurrences of specific operations each day. More exactly, I'm trying to build a chart which will show trends for how User1 has handled his/her orders, e.g. be able to show that User1 has high number of reject/delete operations in 2005 and high number of Approved/Completed operations in 2019. The purpose is to learn how to parse large chunks of data.

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154262/pandas-counting-frequency-of-datetime-objects-in-a-column), which is kinda related to my question. However, the problem is that the df used in this question contains only 2 columns. My df contains 4 columns. Does this mean that I need to first create a new df `(pseudo: df1 = df['Date'] + df['Operation'])` which contains 2 specific columns only or is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is best to create groups based on the day, the user and the Operation.For this you can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`dt.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html).
Then you can count the occurrences of each group using [`groupby.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html). You can use [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to generate a data frame like the one I show you below:

```
#df=df.reset_index() #only if date is the index
#df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) # If Date not is datetime
new_df=df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.date,'Employee','Operation'])['Operation'].count().unstack(fill_value=0)
print(new_df)
```

---

```
Operation            Approved  Created  Deleted  Edited  Rejected
Date       Employee                                              
2001-01-01 User1            1        0        1       1         1
2001-01-02 User1            0        1        0       0         0
```

Also you can use [dt.year](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) 
to group by **year** instead of by day:

```
new_df=df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.year,'Employee','Operation'])['Operation'].count().unstack(fill_value=0)
print(new_df)
Operation      Approved  Created  Deleted  Edited  Rejected
Date Employee                                              
2001 User1            1        1        1       1         1
```

or by year and [month](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
new_df=df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.year,df['Date'].dt.month,'Employee','Operation'])['Operation'].count().unstack(fill_value=0)
print(new_df)
Operation           Approved  Created  Deleted  Edited  Rejected
Date Date Employee                                              
2001 1    User1            1        1        1       1         1
```

---

**Details**

*1. DataFrame for the example:*

```
df

                 Date Employee Operation   Order
0 2001-01-01 08:32:17    User1  Approved  #00045
1 2001-01-01 08:36:23    User1    Edited  #00045
2 2001-01-01 08:41:04    User1  Rejected  #00046
3 2001-01-01 08:42:56    User1   Deleted  #00046
4 2001-01-02 09:01:11    User1   Created  #00047
```

2. If Date is not a column you should use `df=df.reset_index()`. To convert Date to datetime use `df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

Comment: Yep, that the solution I was looking for. The date issue was solved by using `errors='coerce'`.