# Datetime issue when using plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When trying to create a graph using matplotlib, I get `KeyError: 'CreationDate'` error. After reading some topics, I suspect that it might has to do with date column which I'm trying to use as x axis.

The data file is read and parsed before dateframe is created. 
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58354447/count-frequency-of-occurrence-in-column/58354781) is my previous step in learning how count and parse data.

This code snippet was used when parsing csv file:

`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')`

Following code was used to create new df:

`new_df=df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.date,'Employee','Operation'])['Operation'].count().unstack(fill_value=0)`

`new_df:
Operation                    Approved  Created  Deleted  Edited  Rejected
Date         Employee

2018-10-23   User1             2             0              1           0
2018-10-26   User1             6             0              0           1
2018-10-29   User1             6             0              0           1
2018-10-30   User1             1             0              0           0
2018-10-31   User1             3             0              0           0
2018-11-14   User1            10             0              0           1
2018-11-15   User1             4             0              0           1
2018-11-19   User1             5             0              0           1
2018-11-26   User1             5             0              0           1
2018-11-29   User1             1             0              0           0
2018-11-30   User1             2             0              0           0
2018-12-03   User1             8             0              0           2
2018-12-04   User1             5             0              0           0
2018-12-06   User1             1             0              0           0
2018-12-07   User1             5             2              0           0
2018-12-10   User1             7             0              0           1
2018-12-13   User1             1             0              0           0
2018-12-14   User1             1             0              0           0
2018-12-17   User1             5             0              0           1`

What I don't really understand is why matplotlib is throwing this error. CreationDate column has been converted to datetime when creating new df.

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a graph for the data presented above.

Comment: Could you show the code you use with matplotlib? I provide you with the code you have shown. simply by making `new_df.plot (kind = 'bar') `you can represent a bar chart

Comment: I reccomend you `new_df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)`

Comment: Hello @ansev! Thanks for the latest reply. I've tried different solutions, but the latest was this one:  `plt.plot(new_df['CreationDate'], df['FileAccessed'])
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical') `. I'm trying to assign CreationDate to the X axis.

Comment: Creationdate not is in new_df

Comment: Oh, that's wrong clipboard. In my case it should look like `plt.plot(new_df['Date'], df['Operation']) plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')` but It doesn't work either. The snippet you provided does work! I'm reading docs to find out how to specify x axis.

Comment: A bit closer to understanding the problem: when looking for columns in `new_df`, it is missing `Date` column: `print(new_df.columns.tolist()): ['Approved',  'Created',  'Deleted',  'Edited',  'Rejected'] `

Comment: I've managed to copy all columns, but now I'm checking why I'm getting None of Index X are in columns error.

Comment: Actually, problem is solved by using .reset_index() while creating new_df.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't shown all code, but may be this tips will help:

```
list_dates = df['Date']. #Date - column from your new dataframe after grouping
conv_dates = list(map(pd.to_datetime, list_dates))
plt.plot(conv_dates, YOUR_DATA...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I commented in answer above that it seems like my new_df is missing Date column for some reason.

Comment: The parsed data looks like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58354447/count-frequency-of-occurrence-in-column/58354781. Unparsed data includes a lot of double qoutes, backslashes and {};: which are removed while reading the file